# C++ STL Multithreading, running computation in parallel

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, stl

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <thread>
#include <stdio.h>


// Determines if a point of dimension point.size() is within the sphere
bool isPointWithinSphere(std::vector<int> point, const double &radius) {

    // Since we know that the sphere is centered at the origin, we can     simply
    // find the euclidean distance (square root of the sum of squares) and check to
    // see if it is less than or equal to the length of the radius 

    //square each element inside the point vector
    std::transform(point.begin(), point.end(), point.begin(), [](auto &x){return std::pow(x,2);});

    //find the square root of the sum of squares and check if it is less than or equal to the radius
return std::sqrt(std::accumulate(point.begin(), point.end(), 0, std::plus<int>())) <= radius;    
}

// Counts the number of lattice points inside the sphere( all points (x1 .... xn) such that xi is an integer )

// The algorithm: If the radius is a floating point value, first find the floor of the radius and cast it to 
// an integer. For example, if the radius is 2.43 then the only integer points we must check are those between
// -2 and 2. We generate these points by simulating n - nested loops using recursion and passing each point
// in to the boolean function isPointWithinSphere(...), if the function returns true, we add one to the count
// (we have found a lattice point on the sphere). 

int countLatticePoints(std::vector<int> &point, const double radius, const int dimension, int count = 0) {

    const int R = static_cast<int>(std::floor(radius));

    for(int i = -R; i <= R; i++) {
        point.push_back(i);

        if(point.size() == dimension){
            if(isPointWithinSphere(point, radius)) count++;
        }else count = countLatticePoints(point, radius, dimension, count);

        point.pop_back();
    }

    return count;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
std::vector<int> vec {};

std::vector<std::thread> threads;
auto max_threads = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();

for(unsigned i = 0; i < max_threads; ++i)
    threads.push_back(std::thread(countLatticePoints, vec, atof(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2])));

    std::for_each(threads.begin(), threads.end(),  std::mem_fn(&std::thread::join));

    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to run the above computation in parallel. Basically, I want to call the function `countLatticePoints(vec, 1.05, 3)` so that the maximum number of threads on my system are running the computation and returning one final result. I am having difficulty in setting this up. What I have tried is to have all the threads join my computation but I am receiving the following very undecipherable error message.

```
 g++ nDimensionalSphere.cpp -o nDimensionalSphere -std=c++14 -pthread
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:39:0,
                 from nDimensionalSphere.cpp:6:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<int (*(std::vector<int>, double, int))(std::vector<int>&, double, int, int)>’:
/usr/include/c++/4.9/thread:140:47:   required from ‘std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = int (&)(std::vector<int>&, double, int, int); _Args = {std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >&, double, int}]’
nDimensionalSphere.cpp:56:92:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1665:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<int (*(std::vector<int>, double, int))(std::vector<int>&, double, int, int)>’
       typedef typename result_of<_Callable(_Args...)>::type result_type;
                                                             ^
/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1695:9: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<int (*(std::vector<int>, double, int))(std::vector<int>&, double, int, int)>’
         _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Indices...>)
         ^
```

Comment: In addition to the compilation error you have a much larger problem. It appears that each thread will attempt to `push_back`() to the same `std::vector`. Since `std::vector` goes not guarantee thread safety, this will result in undefined behavior.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Oh but the `pop_back` at the end of the loop is even more fun :)

Comment: Yeah, this whole thing is just beyond the point of being salvageable.

Comment: I get the correct answer and the program works perfectly when working sequentially. I simply want to parallelize the computation.

Comment: Parallelizing the computation isn't as simple as just kicking off a bunch of threads for the same code. Multithreading introduces a number of concurrency and locking issues that must be correctly handled. Like I said: `std::vector` is not thread-safe. You cannot have multiple threads `push_back()` and `pop_back()` from the same vector without proper mutex-locking. Full stop. End of story.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Can I create a unique std::vector for each thread that joins my computation so that they aren't referencing the same vector ?

Comment: On top of @SamVarshavchik statements, you're joining threads quite wrong. Get the book like `Anthony Williams, C++ Concurrency in Action` and read it

Comment: Permute your points iteratively (without recursion) and it becomes easier to partition the workload across a number of threads.

Comment: The STL has no threading code in it.  Do you mean `std` library?

Comment: Isn't the error because countLatticePoints takes four arguments (one is optional) and the bind created by the thread constructor has three  arguments?  All the arguments (including default ones) need to be specified or the template magic doesn't work.  So just adding that last argument to the std::thread constructor would help?

Answer (score 0):

This is the important compilation error:

`/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional: In instantiation of ‘struct std::_Bind_simple<int (*(std::vector<int>, double, int))(std::vector<int>&, double, int, int)>’:`

The compiler is detecting that countLatticePoints accepts a reference to a vector but an actual vector is being passed.  You can make it compile by passing a reference to a vector with std::ref like this:

`threads.push_back(std::thread(&countLatticePoints, std::ref(vec), atof(argv[1]), atoi(argv[2]), 0 /*the default parameter*/));`

**But that is a BAD idea** because now all the threads are sharing the one vector and since vectors aren't threadsafe you are just walking into a disaster.

You could change countLatticePoints to accept an actual vector and then you wouldn't need the std::ref any more.  The function then gets it's own vector which is threadsafe but then every thread does the entire vector **which is not what you want**.

The answer to all this is to pass each thread its own actual vector (not a reference) to be threadsafe but construct each vector from an iterator pair so that it contains only a fraction of the items so that every thread gets a different set of data.

There are other problems like how the threads are being joined but they need a new question because they are unrelated to the question you asked.